# Why are some of my questions highlighted in blue?

Tags: support, questions

I was looking at the newest questions tab and noticed two of them have a blueish background. Is this something new? If so, what does it represent?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions which are highlighted in blue are the ones which contain the tags you've favourited or [have been actively involved](https://superuser.com/users/150754/carl-b?tab=tags).

The highlight is to indicate that you might be interested in those questions, based on your past activity.

Comment: on the [su] homepage, you can check your favourite & ignored tags http://i.imgur.com/AsZQquk.png